# How to sign a message with an EC key retrieved from a .PEM file (ECDSA signature)

Tags: c++

I generated an EC private/public key with this OpenSSL command Line:

```
ecparam -out ec_key.pem -name sect571r1 -genkey
```

Is it possible to retrieve the EC_KEY from the ec_key.pem to use it to sign a message with ECDSA?

Answer (score 0):

You can sign the message but have to use some PKI library like PolarSSL. With .Net you have integrated PKI support but not in C++.

Comment: i can't use the PKI in my pgm, because i'm in wireless sensor networks, and since they have a very limited resources, the PKI will consume a lot of energy

Comment: PKI is common term - if you need ECDSA encryption you can include only necessary modules from PolarSSL (or similar library). If the MCU has insufficient memory then the answer is "no".